# TFS Attachement size 0KB via REST Call

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Whenever i tried to attach attachment with TFS WorkItem via REST call, attachment size is 0KB.

First I upload an attachment in Attachment Store using below code.

```
https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/attachments?api-version=1.0&filename="{fileName}"
```

I send data in bytes array through rest call. and after this i attach that attachment with workitem.

Attaching attachment is success but size of an attachment is zero KB
Is there is an issue with TFS or something i am doing wrong?

I am using C# language for programming and REST Sharp for accessing VSTS APIs

```
 Dim restClient = New RestClient("Server URL")

    restClient.Authenticator = New HttpBasicAuthenticator("UserId", "Password")

    Dim request = New RestRequest("API_Name", Method.POST)

    request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = False

    request.AddParameter(String.Format("{0}; charset=utf-8", contentType), File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), ParameterType.RequestBody)

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json

    Dim response As IRestResponse = restClient.Execute(request)

    Return response
```

I am sending file data in bytes.

Attaching Attachment with WorkItem.

```
    Dim restClient = New RestClient(ACCESS_URL)
    restClient.Authenticator = New HttpBasicAuthenticator(USER_NAME, PASSWORD)
    Dim request = New 
    RestRequest("CollectionName}/_apis/wit/workitems/{WorkItem_ID}", Method.PATCH)

   request.AddParameter("application/json-patch+json; charset=utf-8", 
   "post_Data", ParameterType.RequestBody)

   request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json

   Dim response As IRestResponse = restClient.Execute(request)
   Return response
```

Post_Data is an json string which take this type of data

```
[{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "AttachedFile",
      "url": "AttachementURI",

    }]
```

Comment: What's the "contentType" you use in your code? I tested your code with "application/octet-stream" content type, it works correctly. The attachment size is correct and it can be opened successfully.

Comment: yup i am using application/octet-stream but my attachment size is always 0K, are you using extact same code which i have posted or you make some changes?

Comment: Yes, almost the same. I added my code in the answer for your reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed "attributes" section in the Post_Data, try with below:

```
[{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
    "rel": "AttachedFile",
    "url": "AttachementURI",
    "attributes": {
       }
}]
```

Comment: is there any change, it is same which i have posted. What is the catch here ?

Comment: No, and I noticed that you are actually using VB rather than C#, so I created a VB project to test the code. It still works. What's the version of your TFS server? How do you add the attachment to the work item after it is uploaded? What's the file type you are trying to upload?

Comment: TFS Server version is 2017update2 and it also with VSTS. i am editing my question which shows code for attaching work item.

Comment: is VSTS or TFS 2017 rest API are platform dependent and i uses same content type which you use "application/octet-stream"

Comment: Hi Eddie sorry for delay, i am add attributes with comment but no such progress. can you help me to solve this issue.

Comment: @NitinParashar What's the result you get now? I can see that the attachment size is 0KB after remove the attributes and correct attachment size with attributes added. Can you share the Post_Data with attributes added?

Comment: Thanks for your help, its worked attribute is necessary for showing the size of attachment, but i was thinking , VSTS or TFS not to accept rest api until it is not in proper form.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue when keep the `{ file-contents }` as empty.

So, make sure you have specified the `{ file-contents }`.

> To attach a file to a work item, [upload the attachment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/attachments#upload-an-attachment) to the
>   attachment store, then attach it to the work item. See [Add an attachment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#add-an-attachment) for details.

***Upload an attachment:***

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/attachments?api-version={version}&filename=Spec.txt
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
{ file-contents }
```

***Add an attachment for specific work item:***

```
PATCH https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/299?api-version=1.0
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json
[
  {
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/rev",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.History",
    "value": "Adding the necessary spec"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "AttachedFile",
      "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/attachments/098a279a-60b9-40a8-868b-b7fd00c0a439?fileName=Spec.txt",
      "attributes": {
        "comment": "Spec for the work"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

See below C# sample to upload and add the attachment for a work item:

- [C# (UploadTextFile method)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/WorkItemTracking/AttachmentsSample.cs#L23)
- [C# (AddAttachment method)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/WorkItemTracking/WorkItemsSample.cs#L547)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy for your response i am using rest sharp post method for uploading data in that scenario it shows zero kb for file attachment.

Comment: @NitinParashar What's that mean "using rest sharp post method"? Are you using the REST API mentioned in above answer (Upload an attachment:) to  upload the file? Where shows zero kb for the file attachment? Could you please share the detail steps to reproduce the issue, capture screenshot if necessary.

Comment: Andy i am using C# language and REST Sharp post method for attachment i edit my above question please refer for clarification

Comment: @NitinParashar Please refer to the sample for [C# (UploadTextFile method)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/WorkItemTracking/AttachmentsSample.cs#L23)  and [C# (AddAttachment method)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/WorkItemTracking/WorkItemsSample.cs#L547)

Comment: Andy i am not using wrapper classes of VSTS REST API i am creating my own module which post attachment with rest api